# Problem with vehicle routing problem in Gurobi Python

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi, vehicle-routing

I have a vehicle routing problem solved by linear programming, but I'm confused about the constraints (see the model in figure 1). In the model, $u$ and $x$ are decision variables, and we set node $0$ as the depot, nodes $1$ to $n$ as customers. Constraints 1 & 2 indicate that there can only be one edge for both going into and out of the CUSTOMER nodes. However, when I use Gurobi optimizer to solve it, I find the solution always includes the depot (node $0$. See a solution in figure 2). Even I set the depot to an extremely far location (figure 3), the depot is still in the solution. Theoretically, to minimize the objective function, if there are no constraints about the edges into and out of the depot, then $x_{0i}$ and $x_{i0}$ should always be 0. The constraints about the depot can be like $\sum x_{i0} \ge 1$, but there are no such constraints in the model.

This is the code used for adding constraints:

```
mdl.addConstrs(   # mdl is the name of the model
    quicksum(x[i, j] for j in V if j != i) == 1 for i in N)  # only one edge into customer node i
mdl.addConstrs(
    quicksum(x[i, j] for i in V if i != j) == 1 for j in N)  # only one edge out of customer node i
mdl.addConstrs((x[i, j] == 1) >> (u[i] + q[i] == u[j]) for i, j in A if i != 0 and j != 0)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] >= q[i] for i in N)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] <= Q for i in N)
```

Now I'm confident that my code is not problematic (if anyone want to check it I've put it on my Github: https://github.com/KaiyuWei/VRP-problem-by-Gurobi--Python), then could anyone explain the reason why the depot is always included? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your first two constraints are over the set $V$, which is all of your nodes including the depot.

Comment: @EhsanK are you sure ? "mdl.addConstrs(quicksum(x[i, j] for j in V if j != i) == 1 for i in N)"

Comment: @kaiyu wei could you try running the code without the capacity constraints ? Maybe it needs to initialize the $u_i$ variable at the depot to $0$.

Comment: @EhsanK  "for i in N ", not include the depot

Comment: @Kuifje and @kaiyu wei: let's say you have nodes 0 to 3. Isn't this what the constraint says? (your `for i in N` is fine. You sum over $V$ that includes 0) `x[1,0]+x[1,2]+x[1,3] = 1`. Do the same with the second flow balance constraint too.

Comment: @Kuifje I did it, and the depot is not included. But capacity constraint here actually play a role as subcycle eliminator, So subcycles are there under such a circumstance. I think the reason why the depot is always included in the solution may be the capacity constraint.  But you see the constraint, I already write i != 0 and j != 0 so why Python still initialize it?

Comment: @EhsanK  Although x[1, 0] is included in the constraint x[1,0]+x[1,2]+x[1,3] = 1, but this constraint doesn't promise that x[1, 0] certainly gains value 1, so as the other constraints.

Comment: @kaiyuwei you have those flow balance constraints and you also have the subtour elimination one. Try it on a piece of paper with only 3 nodes of 0, 1, 2. Assuming all `q !=0`, Is it possible for you to have, e.g., `u1 + q1 = u2` AND `u2+q2=u1` (that is to say `x[1,2]` and `x[2,1]` both are 1) ? If not, then even though you excluded node 0 in the subtour, you still have them in the flow balance and since a constraint of the form above that I wrote is not possible, then the model chooses to assign a 1 to a variable that enters/leaves the depot.

Comment: So tu sum up, constraints $x_{ij}=1 \Rightarrow u_i +q_j = u_j$ have a subtour elimination role, and therefore no node, including the depot, can be excluded.

Comment: Dear @EhsanK, could you explain abit further?  From my perspective of view, when the constraint `if x_ij = 1 then u_i + q_j = u_j` comes to the last node that enters the depot, it doesn't work since `x_i0 = 1` but we have `j != 0` as a prerequisite. So if there are only 3 nodes 0, 1, 2, the subtour eliminator will only work on `x_12` (or `x_21`).

Comment: Well, there is no constraint on `x_i0` in the subtour elimination constraint. So nothing limits its value there. That's why when you have to select either `x_12=1` or `x21=1`, those `x_i0` or `x_0i` can take a value of 1 according to the first two sets of constraints. I'll write this out in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constraints 1 and 2 ensure that there is an edge going in and out of every node. Constraint 3 works as a subtour elimination and along with the above constraints ensures that there is no subtour and as a result, you must enter and leave the depot.

A simple illustration is to assume there are only 3 nodes. So: $ V = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and $ N = \{1,2\}$. Let's spell out the constraints as coded:

\begin{align}
x_{10}+x_{12}&= 1 \tag1\\
x_{20}+x_{21}&= 1 \tag2\\
x_{01}+x_{21}&= 1 \tag3\\
x_{02}+x_{12}&= 1 \tag4\\
\mbox{if } x_{12} = 1 \rightarrow u_1+q_1 &= u_2 \tag5\\
\mbox{if } x_{21} = 1 \rightarrow u_2+q_2 &= u_1 \tag6\\
q_1 \le u_1 &\le Q \tag7\\
q_2 \le u_2 &\le Q \tag8\\
\end{align}

Note that only the first two sets of constraints (equations 1 to 4 above) have anything to do with the depot. If you're wondering why the edges of node $0$ are selected in the solution, let's consider the case that they are not and see if that's possible with the constraints above.

In case you don't want to see an edge from/to depot, that means you want $x_{10}, x_{20}, x_{01}, x_{02}$ to be zero. If you substitute this in the constraints above, you'll have $x_{12}=x_{21}=1$.

However, you cannot have $x_{12} = x_{21} = 1$, because constraints 5 and 6 above cannot both be true at the same time, unless $q_1 = q_2 = 0$.

Now, from here work backwards for yourself. For example, let $x_{12} = 1$:

$x_{12} = 1 \rightarrow \mbox{(equations 1 and 4) } x_{10}=x_{02}=0$

$\mbox{if } x_{12} = 1 \rightarrow \mbox{(equations 5 and 6) } x_{21}=0 \rightarrow \mbox{(equations 2 and 3) } x_{20}=x_{01}=1$

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me.